# How to get Neo4j nodes linked through another node?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have node A and an associated node B.
Node C and node D are tied to node B too.
It is necessary to get all nodes A and associated with them C and D

```
MATCH (a:A) -- (:B) -- (c:C) 
RETURN a, c
```

Received A and bound to it (via B) C.
Is it possible get node A, C and D in the same request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your query in two ways like below:

Option #1:

```
MATCH (a:A) -- (b:B) -- (c:C), (b) -- (d:D)
RETURN a, c, d
```

Option #2:

```
MATCH (a:A) -- (b:B) -- (c:C)
MATCH (b) -- (d:D)
RETURN a, c, d
```

which is basically the same thing with the first query.